# 500 Internal Server Error after uploading to a host

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, mod-rewrite

I have searched all day in this forum and found same problems like mine,tried all the answers but just wont work.

In my locahost, everthing is fine, but later when I decided to upload it to a live webserver, it starts showing

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator,
>   webmaster@reportingsystem.cnnpa.com and inform them of the time
>   the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have
>   caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

In my error log I've seen this:

```
[Tue Jan 29 22:05:53 2013] [error] [client 112.198.77.50] File does not exist: /home/cnnpa/crs/404.shtml
[Tue Jan 29 22:05:53 2013] [error] [client 112.198.77.50] File does not exist: /home/cnnpa/crs/crimeindex
```

I think this has something to do with .htaccess and mod_rewrite based on reading similar questions. When I remove .htaccess it seems to work, but I dont want this solution because at the first place I used .htaccess for the purpose of having a cleaner URL's(by removing the index.php).

Here is my current .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /crs/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

in my config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://reportingsystem.cnnpa.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: I think there's a problem in your file and directory permissions

Comment: Is `404.shtml` file present on server?

Comment: how big is the file you are trying to upload?

Comment: @KalpeshMehta, all of my folders permission are set to 755 and all files are set to 644

Comment: @YogeshSuthar, I dont know why it gives me error about missing files.Im pretty sure I have no files like that.This files are not even in the codeigniter default package.

Comment: @keeg, I've already uploaded my files to a server

Comment: so the error comes up after upload, but the files are there?

Comment: Are you sure you have rewrite module enabled? Have you tried commenting out `RewriteBase` directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteBase /crs/
```

My first suspect will be the [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) value in your htaccess file.

Looking at your config.php it seems you are serving the application out from the DocumentRoot.  if that is the case the RewriteBase should be written as below.

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: This works! What I know about rewrite base is the name of the folder containing of my files for my website