# Base Path not recognized on live server

Tags: codeigniter, path, base-url

My path to media folder (css) worked fine on localhost but on live server it does not recognize it. All I changed was system and application path in index.php to website/system and website/application. URL-helper is auto-loaded. Base_url is set to http://website.com/

Here is the folder structure:

Root-Folders: Apache Logs, Error Logs, Website

Website-Folders: Application, Media, System

Media-Folders: css

CSS-File: style.css

Here is e.g. my css inclusion:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('media/css/style.css'); ?>" />
```

When I include the css internally it works so it is definetly a path-issue. I tried several things with base_url but yeah no success. Thanks for any help!

My .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the default file for indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
php_flag short_open_tags on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # mod_rewrite rules
    RewriteEngine on

    # The RewriteBase of the system (if you are using this sytem in a sub-folder).
    #RewriteBase /cmp/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# If Mod_ewrite is NOT installed go to index.php
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the contents of the `Website` folder to the `root` and try once.

Comment: Thanks for this. That should be the solution as it makes absolutely sense. I did this and changed index.php file paths back to 'system' and 'application'. What happens now though is I get internal server error 500. Do you have an idea what could be causing this?

Comment: You need .htaccess configuration, have you checked that?

Comment: I have my usual .htaccess in root: I added it to the question. Do you know what is wrong in there?

Comment: $config['index_page'] = ''; is set empty and I changed #RewriteBase / but still error 500

Comment: Ok I got it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585327/500-internal-server-error-after-uploading-to-a-host?rq=1 Thanks for the solution and .htaccess trail...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url().'media/css/style.css'; ?>" />
```